# Maximum subset of words with Hamming distance ≥ D

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, coding-theory

For all words of fixed length L over a given alphabet, I am interested in a practical algorithm that can give me a subset of maximal cardinality such that the Hamming distance between any two words in the subset equals D. 
(The following variation is also of great interest: ... Hamming distance between any two words in the subset is at least D.)

Is there a mathematical result about the cardinality of such sets, depending on the alphabet, the length L of the words, and the minimum distance D?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Isn't the variation just asking for MDS code?

Comment: As Yonatan hinted, please check the theory of error correcting codes.  There are many results about your question.  I cannot see a particular connection to MDS codes, though.

Comment: can you please be bothered to state a relevant one "of the many results about my question"? i could not find one, which is why i am asking in this forum.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound and references therein

Comment: I think that this should be an answer. It's a valid question and a clear answer.

Comment: @Suresh: Feel free to post an answer if you want to.

Comment: Well it's your answer, not mine :)

Comment: You can find a few implementations if you Google for "hamming usaco" (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hamming+usaco). (It is one of the training problems for the USA Computing Olympiad.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In coding theory, the quantity you are looking for is called $A_q(n, d)$, where $n$ is the length of vectors, $d$ is the minimum distance between them, and $q$ is the alphabet size (omitted when $q=2$). Characterizing $A_q(n,d)$ is a challenging open problem (with many basic questions remaining unanswered) but various asymptotic and non-asymptotic upper and lower bounds are known. See Chapter 17 of the book "The Theory of Error-Correcting Codes" by MacWilliams and Sloane for a summary of the most important ones.

Answer (score 2):

In general this is an open problem, so you should not expect anything like a clean formula or an algorithm. For linear codes (at least) an awful lot is known. The authors of

http://mint.sbg.ac.at/desc_CBrouwerTable-Bound.html

maintain a database of everything(?) that is known about this problem (lower bounds, upper bounds, constructions).

Answer (score -3):

Try the following command on MATLAB, as you're looking for a practical solution

```
squareform(pdist(dec2bin(0:255,8),'hamming')*8)
```

It gives you a matrix, containing the pairwise hamming distance between binary numbers from 0 to 255.
You can plot it using any tool in matlab, such as 'imtool'. But be careful about the 1-based indexing of matrices in MATLAB!